# Yii2 tabs active not working

Tags: yii2

I have a tab widget like below.

```
<?php
echo \yii\bootstrap\Tabs::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Administrators',
            'url' => Url::to(['/admin/admin']),
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Members Tracker',
            'url' => Url::to(['/admin/members']),
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Pages',
            'url' => Url::to(['/admin/pages']),
        ],
    ],
]); 
?>
```

Tabs are appearing correctly. But the active is not working for other tabs. Only active appears to first tab. If we click on other tabs('member Tracker','Pages') it routes correctly and can view the page contents. But tab1('Administrators") is in open state and other tabs in closed state. How to make a tab active when we click on it and others closed.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Yii2 Bootstrap Tabs Widget](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.2/yii-bootstrap-tabs) you can use `active` option.

For example in `AdminController` set `$action` to current action and pass to the view file:

```
<?= \yii\bootstrap\Tabs::widget([
     'items' => [
         [
             'label' => 'Administrators',
             'url' => Url::to(['/admin/admin']),
             'active' => $action == 'admin',
         ],
         [
             'label' => 'Members Tracker',
             'url' => Url::to(['/admin/members']),
             'active' => $action == 'members',
         ],
         [
             'label' => 'Pages',
             'url' => Url::to(['/admin/pages']),
             'active' => $action == 'pages',
         ],
     ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What i understand is that when you click on any of the tabs your page redirects, and you donot want the page to reload or redirect when you click on any of the tabs.
If that is correct then this is because you are using the `url` option and it takes a full route and redirects to that url, to use basic tab functionality you have to use the `content` option to display the text for the desired tab or you can load the view too see below

```
<?php
echo \yii\bootstrap\Tabs::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Administrators',
            //using a view file
            'content' => $this->render('some-view'),
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Members Tracker',
            //using static content
            'content' => 'This is some content for Member Tracker Tab'
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Pages',
            'content' => 'This is some content for Pages Tab'
        ],
    ],
])
?>
```